# executing a desktop app in linux by command line without showing its GUI window

Tags: linux, command-line, framebuffer, xserver

I have an windowed App (f.i. an App with a graphic or GUI X-window) which takes a text file as input (stdin) and writes an output text file. During computation, it briefly opens a window which is necessary for graphical computations and then the app quits. How can I integrate this program in a purely textual and automated batch environment of a shell in linux? When I try to just run it in the shell then of course I get an error "Can't open display".

Is there a way to keep the APP window hidden such that it can run purely in the shell?

(in my case it is actually an AIR app, but I hope this is solvable in general for all kinds of xwindow-based apps)

Comment: can't you have an xserver running someplace that can service the call? it doesn't have to be on the same box, although that is easier to manage. Else, dbl-check the app's manual to see if it has a silent or batch mode? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I already considered an extra xserver machine, but I hope to avoid it. Regarding the app's manual, the app was written by myself in Adobe AIR and it uses a complex 3rd party library which requires a window. There is no alternative. Maybe AIR itself has a possibility to run apps silently, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I can answer my own question. The answer is: Xvfb. It provides a 'fake' virtual framebuffer.

In Ubuntu linux I did:

```
apt-get install xvfb
```

After installation a xvfb-run wrapper script became available which does exactly what I need:

```
xvfb-run myapp
```

Perfect!